# Find the period of a state in a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_n:n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be a Markov chain with transition probabilities as given below:

[image]

> Determine the period of each state.

The answer is "The only state with period $> 1$ is $1$, which has period $3$. I don't understand why other states like $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$ are not with period $3$, they can also take $3$ steps back to themselves, can't them?

Comment: You're right.  All states except state $4$ takes $3n$ steps back to itself.

Answer (score 2):

The period of a state $i$ is
$$d(i) = \mathrm{gcd}\{n : P_{ii}^n > 0 \}. $$
If two states $i$ and $j$ communicate, that is, there exist $m,n>0$ such that $P_{ij}^n>0$ and $P_{ji}^m>0$, then $d(i)=d(j)$. By inspection, states $1, 2, 3, 5, 6$ all communicate. So you are correct.

Comment: Should lcd be gcd?

Comment: @MickA Indeed that must have been a typo, fixed.